# Copying files from one folder to multiple other folders (all within one main folder) based on file name

Tags: python, copy

I'm relatively new to python and although I can understand code (for the most part), I have trouble with starting to write code, so any help is appreciated. This is also my first time posting on stackoverflow so please go easy on me as O still don't know all the rules of posting.

I'm working on a project that involves copying many csv. files from one folder (let's call it 'Data' to multiple other folders, all of which are located within a single main folder (e.g., 'Main folder' > 'site_1', 'site_2', 'site_3', etc.). The file names consist of a sequence of numbers (e.g., a serial number) and the folders they need to be copied to are named based on the site the data were collected from. There is also a separate file (csv format) that connects the data files to the location, and includes both the serial number and site name. There are also multiple files that need to be copied over for each site.

I've been doing some digging into this and it appears that some variation of `shutil.copy()` would be the best option. I just don't know where to start and how to utilize the file that contains the site name and file serial number to copy these files over to their proper folders. Some of the files were manually copied into their respective folders, so I'd like the code to be able to skip these and only add new ones as new files are added to the 'Data' folder.

In the 'Data Folder', I currently have files as such:

- 123.csv
- 456.csv
- 789.csv
- 111.csv
- 222.csv
- 333.csv
- 444.csv
- 555.csv

I want these files to be copied over to their respective site folders as such:

- site_1 -> 123.csv, 456.csv, 789.csv
- site_2 -> 111.csv, 222.csv, 333.csv
- site_3 -> 444.csv, 555.csv

This would be based on the connecting file that has the following structure:

```
| siteName | serialNumber |
| -------- | ------------ |
| site_1   | 123          |
| site_1   | 456          |
| site_1   | 789          |
| site_2   | 111          |
| site_2   | 222          |
| site_2   | 333          |
| site_3   | 444          |
| site_3   | 555          |
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just read the file, and `shutil.copy` based on it? What exactly is the problem? any errors?

Comment: Daviid, I need the files to be copied over to the correct folder based on the file name and I don't know how to streamline the code to do that. I'm new to writing python scripts so I just don't really know where to start with this.

Comment: Does your connecting file have to be in that format? If it could be simplified to remove the pipe symbols and unnecessary white space it would simplify the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you can change your connecting file to be a csv file for now...

```
import os
import shutil


# Load the contents of the connecting file...
mapper = {}
with open('connecting_file.csv', 'r') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i == 0:
            # Skip the column headers.
            continue

        site_name, serial_number = line.split(',')
        mapper[serial_number] = site_name


# Start copying files...
folder_contents = os.listdir('Data')
print(f'Found {len(folder_contents)} files in the Data directory')

for filename in folder_contents:
    # I'm assuming the files are actually named with 3 digits,
    # if not, a change will be needed below.
    prefix = filename[0:3]
    destination_folder = mapper.get(prefix, None)
    # If prefix is not in mapper, display some details
    # and skip on to the next filename.
    if destination_folder is None:
        print(f'Unable to find {prefix} in mapper!')
        print(filename)
        continue

    destination_filename = os.path.join('Main folder', destination_folder, filename)
    shutil.copyfile(filename, destination_filename)
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian! The connecting file is indeed a csv file. The only thing I altered was the [0:3] to a [5:13] as the file names start with "data_' and then include the 6-digit serial number. I ran it and am now getting KeyError: '######' (where the #'s are one of the serial numbers). I can't seem to figure out how to get past this error.

Comment: Could it be that the key is not in the connecting file?

Comment: I double checked, it's in there! The traceback is in the line: destination_folder = mapper[prefix] if that helps.

Comment: I added a couple of lines to help debug the issue at that point, and the code will attempt to carry on and copy the next file.

Comment: I re-ran it with the new additions and it printed that it could not find any of the files. Not sure what's going on here since I confirmed all the serial numbers are in the connecting file.

Comment: I added a new line to print out the number of files found in the Data folder. Can you see how many it finds? Could you also add some of the output to your response as I'd like to see exactly what is being returned?